# Feature Selection Per Sample

Tags: time-series, feature-selection

By extraction different features for each sample (data point), is it correct we can train a model of all samples using different features per sample?
I appreciate your response, and if you can refer to any paper, please do so. Thanks

Comment: I do not follow what the means. Could you please give an example of this?

Comment: Say, you extracted features of a signal (in time and frequency domains). Features are f1, f2,...,fm. You learned that some instances (samples or data points) can be best represented by a set of features, but some other instances are best represented by some other set of features. After selecting certain features per sample, can you eventually fit them into a learner? In other words, the feature vector for each sample is different, but with the same length.